# How can I make my image slide show play automatically?

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript, so if this looks terrible I'm sorry.
I've been trying to get my image slideshow to change images every couple of seconds and continue to loop. so far this is what I've got. Any help would be appreciated!

```js
let images = [{
    imageUrl: `images/white.png`
  },
  {
    imageUrl: `images/blue.png`
  },
  {
    imageUrl: `images/black.png`
  }
]
var showImage = 0;

function slideShow(imageIndex) {
  document.getElementById('img1').src = images[imageIndex].imageUrl;
}

function startUp() {
  document.getElementById('img1').src = images[showImage].imageUrl;
}

setTimeout(() => {
  startUp();
  showImage++;
  if (showImage == images.length) {
    showImage = 0
  }
}, 3000)
```

```html
<section id="TOPPICKS">
  <div>
    <p class="designshop">SHOP<br> NOW</p>
  </div>
  <div class="slideshowcontainer">
    <div class="imagecontainer">
      <img class='slideimage' id="img1">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p class="designshop">SHOP<br>NOW</p>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="xcolor1">
  <div class="buttoncontainer">
    <a class="slidebutton" onclick="slideShow(0)"></a>
    <a class="slidebutton" onclick="slideShow(1)"></a>
    <a class="slidebutton" onclick="slideShow(2)"></a>
  </div><br><br>
  <div><a href="products.html" class="shopnow">SHOP NOW</a></div>
</section>
```

Comment: why did you put your images like this in js code? you should put them in a container in HTML and then make an `array` out of it. then use `forEach loop` to show them one by one.

Answer (score 0):

```
            <!-- should put src=firstimage and also width=  and height= 
        Your img1 should be a more sensible name e.g. imageset1
        document.getElementById("imageset1").src="http:mysite.wot/somefolder/image0.jpg";
        is more how I know it to be, there are other ways
    
    document.getElementById("imageset1").src=images[0];   
-->
 let images = [
    
      `http:mysite.wot/somefolder/images/white.png`
    ,
    
        `http:mysite.wot/somefolder/images/blue.png`
    ,
    
       `http:mysite.wot/somefolder/images/black.png`
    
  ];

 
        <img class='slideimage' id="imageset1" onload="startup();" src="http:mysite.wot/somefolder/image0.jpg" width="500" height="300">
```

Comment: So, I actually have ```startup()``` being called upon through the body tag with onload.
could you clarify about src=firstimage?

Comment: Could not figure whether you were trying to use a J's map or collection array or the images "object" system(new Image()) for preload images. Choose an array system way for the correct syntax. Above is standard array X browser array.